Replacing text with link to a google drive file
I'm relatively new to Apps script and am encountering this problem that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to replace text in a doc with the link to a pdf in google drive.  If I use a url to a website the script will run, but when I link to the google drive pdf file I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElement')".  I've pasted the relevant parts of the script below for your reference.  Thanks for the help!
var updateNewDoc=DocumentApp.openById(updateTemplate.getId());
  
  var updateBody=updateNewDoc.getBody();
  
  const updateData=updateSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  updateData.shift();

  
  updateData.forEach((row,i)=>{
    if(row[12]===''){
      const first=row[0];
      const lastName=row[1];
      const about=row[2];
      const linkedin=row[6];
      const resume=row[7];

      let text=''+first+' '+lastName+' - '+about+' ('+resume+') ('+linkedin+')'

      var foundResumeText=updateBody.findText(resume).getElement().asText();
      var startResume=updateBody.findText(resume).getStartOffset();
      var endResume=updateBody.findText(resume).getEndOffsetInclusive();
      var urlResume=foundResumeText.setLinkUrl(startResume,endResume,resume);
      urlResume.replaceText(resume,'Resume');

I expected this to replace the link to the file with the word "resume" and then set the link to the file...so if you click on the word "resume" it would take you to the file.  Instead, the script gets this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElement')".
